# Why doesn't VS Code show the option to display function callers for C/C++?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode 1.78 version on my windows machine to brows c/c++ code. I have installed c/c++ extension pack.  however vscode does not show function caller option in menu for c/c++. what should I do to see this feature?

vscode should show from where given function is called in c/c++.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you not just use "Find All References"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @starball no i can not use find all reference. it is different from showing function caller. find all reference show any use of the function name statically whatever it founds in all project. Function name can be found in header file also as a prototype or in any log also if you have used that name. What i want is i should see on only exact function caller programitally where it is called (not static entries)

Comment: how is that a problem though? Is it failing to disambiguate based on namespaces? Or have you not sufficiently namespaced your things?

Comment: @starball there is a feature in eclipse. if you have build your code by configuring compilers and symbol settings, then you will land to exact function where it is called run time. the jump will not be ambiguous in any case. i was looking similar feature here